# MYSQL Access denied using password(NO)

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I'm not getting my PHP and MySQL working. Here is the code that I am using:

```
<?php
$sitename = "http://xxxx.xxxx.com";
$link = mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com", "a12123xx_sitedb", "xxxxxx");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('a12123xx_sitedb', $link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue)
    {
        if($finder == "1")
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
        else
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row[$rowname];
    }
?>
```

The error I get is:

> Access denied using password(NO)

Yes, I'm using the same user as `dbname` and, by the way, after a while the site crashes and gets a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` message.

Comment: It's probably giving you a subtle message *"Hey...don't use mysql_ functions anymore...."*

Comment: How would I rewrite it?

Comment: Use `PDO` or `mysqli_` instead and make sure your `username`, `password`, and `db` name is correct.

Comment: `$link = mysqli_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com", "a12123xx_sitedb",   "xxxxxx", "a12123xx_sitedb");`  So it would be like this? @Rasclatt

Comment: Spice it up: `$link = new mysqli("mysql15.000webhost.com", "a12123xx_sitedb", "xxxxxx", "a12123xx_sitedb");` Forget that procedural business! :D

Comment: @Niklas - are you running this from your local machine?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP No from 000webhost

Comment: Be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and will be removed entirely from the next version of PHP. You should stop using then and switch your code to either the mysqli or PDO libraries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please dont use `mysql_connect`, that extension is deprecated. Instead of that use `mysqli_connect`.

To solve your problem please make sure your hostname, username and password are correct.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that my information is correct.
What equals mysql_select_db, mysql_query and mysql_fetch_assoc?

Comment: @Niklas - do you have phpmyadmin in that host? If yes try to connect using that

Comment: Instead of mysql_select_db you can use mysqli_select_db. And instead of mysql_query you can use mysqli_query

Comment: `<?php
$sitename = "http://xxxxxx/";
$link = new mysqli("mysql6.000webhost.com", "a15846xx_xx", "xxx", "a15846xx_skinbag");
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db('a15846xx_skinbag', $link);
mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {
 if($finder == "1") $result = mysqli_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
 else $result = mysqli_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 return $row[$rowname];
}
?>`
I changed it, is this right? And I made a new user a new db

Comment: is there anyway I can contact you?

Comment: @Niklas - please check your mail